# xmlpullparser(), whats wrong with my code?

Tags: android, xml

I am expecting output to be an array list filled with all items as "thought"
but instead, every time i add a value into arraylist, the previous value in list also gets update with new, hence resulting in duplicates. This behaviour goes on till end. Even though i have achieved the result by changing the approach, failure of my previous approach still bothers me. Any help or pointer will be really appreciated.

**My debugging observation:** When a second add() method is  encountered, instead of just adding a new element to arraylist, somehow previous element gets altered too.

Below is xml snippet:

```
<Thoughts>

<country>

    <name>India</name>

    <item>

        <itemId>1</itemId>

        <itemDetailImage>detail.png</itemDetailImage>

        <itemImage>image1.png</itemImage>

        <itemDesc>Item Description 1</itemDesc>

        <itemTitle>Item Title 1</itemTitle>

    </item>

    <item>

        <itemId>2</itemId>

        <itemDetailImage>detail2.png</itemDetailImage>

        <itemImage>image2.png</itemImage>

        <itemDesc>Item Description 2</itemDesc>

        <itemTitle>Item Title 2</itemTitle>

    </item>

<item>

        <itemId>3</itemId>

        <itemDetailImage>detail3.png</itemDetailImage>

        <itemImage>image3.png</itemImage>

        <itemDesc>Item Description 3</itemDesc>

        <itemTitle>Item Title 3</itemTitle>

    </item>
```

Below is a method for my trial and error:

```
private void printAll() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{

    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();

    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.3/DefaultXML.xml");
    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();

    parser.setInput(is, null);

    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    String name;
    while(eventType != parser.END_DOCUMENT){
        if(eventType == parser.START_DOCUMENT){
            Log.i(TAG,"Start document");
        }else if (eventType == parser.START_TAG ) {
            name = parser.getName();

            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(NAME)){
                this.cName = new Country();
                this.cName.setName(parser.nextText());
            }else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM_DESC)){
                this.thought.setItemDesc(parser.nextText());
            }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM_ID)) {
                this.thought.setItemID(parser.nextText());
            }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM_DETAIL_IMAGE)) {
                this.thought.setItemDetailImage(parser.nextText());
            }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM_IMAGE)) {
                this.thought.setItemImage(parser.nextText());
            }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM_TITLE)) {
                this.thought.setItemTitle(parser.nextText());
            }

        }else if (eventType == parser.END_TAG) {
            name = parser.getName();
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)) {
                this.cName.setThought(this.thought);
                ctry.add(cName);
                this.thought = new Thought();
            }

        }

        eventType = parser.next();
    }

    //Log.i(TAG,"---" + ctry.toString());

}
```

**Below is the Log info I get:**
    02-23 17:15:30.199: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Start document
02-23 17:15:30.299: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): 4
02-23 17:15:30.299: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): India
02-23 17:15:30.299: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Item Description 4
02-23 17:15:30.299: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): detail4.png
02-23 17:15:30.309: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): image4.png
02-23 17:15:30.309: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Item Title 4--------------
02-23 17:15:30.309: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): 4
02-23 17:15:30.309: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): India
02-23 17:15:30.309: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Item Description 4
02-23 17:15:30.319: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): detail4.png
02-23 17:15:30.319: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): image4.png
02-23 17:15:30.319: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Item Title 4--------------
02-23 17:15:30.319: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): 4
02-23 17:15:30.319: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): India
02-23 17:15:30.329: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Item Description 4
02-23 17:15:30.329: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): detail4.png
02-23 17:15:30.329: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): image4.png
02-23 17:15:30.339: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Item Title 4--------------
02-23 17:15:30.339: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): 4
02-23 17:15:30.339: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): India
02-23 17:15:30.349: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Item Description 4
02-23 17:15:30.349: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): detail4.png
02-23 17:15:30.349: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): image4.png
02-23 17:15:30.349: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Item Title 4--------------
02-23 17:15:30.349: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): 4
02-23 17:15:30.349: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Australia
02-23 17:15:30.349: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Item Description 4
02-23 17:15:30.349: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): detail4.png
02-23 17:15:30.349: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): image4.png
02-23 17:15:30.349: INFO/XmlPullParserActivity(726): Item Title 4--------------

Comment: can you pls eleborate what this means this.cName = new Country(); and impl. of class country.?

Comment: cName is as instance of Country class. Country class contains a String variable named "name" and another variable as instance of "Thought", which itself contains several fields.

Answer (score 2):

Repetition of values are because `this.thought` always refers to the same object.

Since, you are setting values on the same instance, you will get an `ArrayList<Thought>`  with values, read last in parse cycle.

Comment: "this" is implied whether you write it or not. What you have to do is instantiate a new Thought object every time you encounter <thought> node and when you get a </thought> put it in the ArrayList.

Comment: yeah, i knew it. I have already tried ur next suggestion too, but in vain.